# How to move an ellipse in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to move an ellipse having image of football .. i want to move it by using X-Y co-ordinate of  an ellipse ....previously i am moving it with margin and padding but it doesn't give the required output ... anyone please help me ...

```
<TransformGroup>
    <RotateTransform Angle="40" CenterX="0" CenterY="0" />
    <ScaleTransform/>
    <SkewTransform AngleY="-0.963"/>
    <RotateTransform/>
    <TranslateTransform Y="2.221"/>
</TransformGroup>

<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="img2"  Height="20"     
      Source="C:\Users\ATECH\Desktop\project\6.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="570"       
      OpacityMask="#FF955555" RenderTransformOrigin="0.751,0.478" Grid.Row="2"     
      Canvas.Left="253"Canvas.Top="224">
</Image>
```

Comment: How do you want to move it? Some fixed animations or driven by specified actions from `ViewModel` or code behind? Or by some User input?

Comment: @AnatoliiG....sir actually i am making a football game in ball will move when player will hits on it.. so it would be through some event basically...please help me sir ...

Comment: @Sheridan...sorry!ok sir ..next time i will be careful ..

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [Link](https://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/LogOn.aspx?rp=http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15354/Dragging-Elements-in-a-Canvas&download=true)

Or you can Try out this [reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7909c0de-55f8-454f-9b37-1ef00ae67cfc/how-to-move-a-wpf-control-using-mouse-events) too :-